# Marriage certificate of ancestor in Caracas

Tags: marriage-records, locating-records, 1940s, 1930s, venezuela

I am in Europe and have an ancestor who lived in Caracas and married around 1930 to 1940 in Venezuela, most likely in Caracas. He died in 1990.

Where can I find his marriage certificate? Can I request this kind of document online at the local Alcaldía (city hall) in Caracas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Venezuela Civil Registration, 1873-2003](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/1823609) registers available on FamilySearch.org. They contain Births, marriages, deaths, indexes and other records created by civil registration offices in Venezuela.

---

If that doesn't work then definitely contact the local city hall. According to the [US Embassy in caracas](http://caracas.usembassy.gov/mobile//citizen-service/marriage.html):

> The Civil Code states that a civil marriage can only be contracted
>   between a woman and a man, and it **must be performed in the
>   municipality where either the man or the woman resides**.

So the record should be in the Municipality that the marriage took place.

---

You could also try contacting the [Embassy of Venezuela in the United States of America](http://eeuu.embajada.gob.ve/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=67&Itemid=6&lang=en). They might be able to offer more help in English rather than Spanish and probably have experience locating marriage records. Or contact whichever Embassy of Venezuela is applicable for your country of residence in Europe.

Comment: ...Or contact whichever Embassy of Venezuela is applicable for Til's country of residence in Europe.

Comment: Added that to the answer, thanks @bgwiehle